# Wamp server slow on subsequent refresh in windows 8

Tags: php, wamp

I have wampserver 2.2 running on my windows 8 which I use in testing my php codes.

On initial refresh/load the page loads fast but on subsequent refresh it takes a whole LOT of time to reload. Its really frustrating!!! 
Anyone with an idea to fix this? or a better alternative to wamp. (I have tried changing my localhost to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file and disabling my IPV6 yet it persist!).

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You dont actually specify where your speed issue is. 
If its a database speed issue, this has worked in the past.

Anyway, try changing your database connection instruction from using a host of `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

So for example:

```
//$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=localhost';
$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';
$options = array(......);

$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password, $options);
```

OR if you are using the old mysql_* extension

```
//$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$link = mysql_connect('127.0.0.1', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
```

I have no idea why this makes a difference but it does appear to.

Comment: this is the solution indeed.
Don't forget to alter this for your phpmyadmin as well (config file)